# is there any way to use the values from a list in an sql lite database

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

the goal for this project is to webscrape data from a table and put the results into an sqllite database however i don't know if the current way i'm trying to go about it is possible. currently the data is stored in a list seperated by each row on the table, the only issue is trying to insert it into the database. The error I find with this code is an incomplete input for the sql insert.
i've tried searching online for a solution but nothing so far has helped, it will either cause this issue or a list index out of range.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sqlite3
headers = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"}
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_viruses"
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
row_list= list()
for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    row_list.append(row)
print(row_list)
print(row_list[1][1])
maldb = sqlite3.connect("maldb")
cursor = maldb.cursor()
cursor.execute('''drop table if exists mal''')
cursor.execute('''create table mal
            (virus text primary key,
            alias text,
            typeof text,
            subtype text,
            isolation_date text,
            isolation text,
            origin text,
            author text,
            notes text)
''')
for z in range(1,95):
    cursor.execute('''INSERT into mal ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')''',(row_list[z][0],row_list[z][1],row_list[z][2],row_list[z][3],row_list[z][4],row_list[z][5],row_list[z][6],row_list[z][7],row_list[z][8]))
maldb.commit()
maldb.close()
```

Comment: You'd better checkout the INSERT syntax from Postgres doc. Try do narrow the issue two the relevant exception, eventually providing the actual content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different problems here. The first one is that your syntax is incorrect: you shall not quote the `?` characters, so at least your query should be:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT into mal (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(row_list[z][0],row_list[z][1],row_list[z][2],row_list[z][3],row_list[z][4],row_list[z][5],row_list[z][6],row_list[z][7],row_list[z][8]))
```

Worse, some rows have not 9 items (first has none, and another one has only 8), so you should check for that. Finally, it is better to use `executemany` that looping over `execute`, because the query is only compiled once. So I would suggest:

```
cursor.executemany('''INSERT into mal values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
                   [row for row in row_list if len(row) == 9])
```

Finally, you should not use a `PRIMARY KEY` attribute for the `virus` column, because the list actually contains a duplicate for `'Jerusalem\n'` while a primary key has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. the syntax is incorrect: you want.
2. you are setting the 'Virus' values as your primary key, but `'Jerusalem'` is in there twice. You cant have the more than 1 row with same value as the primary key.
3. I would just use pandas to parse the html `<table>` tags.
4. while you CAN iterate through each row to add it, there is also a method to write multiple/all the rows at once with `executemany()` method. See [here](https://pythonexamples.org/python-sqlite3-insert-multiple-rows-to-table/)

Code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_viruses")[1]

maldb = sqlite3.connect("maldb.db")
cursor = maldb.cursor()
cursor.execute('''drop table if exists mal''')
cursor.execute('''create table mal
            (virus text primary key,
            alias text,
            typeof text,
            subtype text,
            isolation_date text,
            isolation text,
            origin text,
            author text,
            notes text)
''')

for idx, row in table.iterrows():
    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO mal (virus, alias, typeof, subtype, isolation_date, isolation, origin, author, notes ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        val = (row['Virus'],row['Alias(es)'],row['Types'],row['Subtype'],row['Isolation Date'],row['Isolation'],row['Origin'],row['Author'],row['Notes'])
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        print (val)

maldb.commit()
maldb.close()
```